# For some reason, the jquery code is not working on my site under IE 8, but is giving off no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's working fine under chrome, anyone have an idea on what tool I could use to check what is wrong? Or where to look?

This is the whole code if anyone is interested, but I doubt it would be of use.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).blur();
    });
    $('.opcion').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('color','#FFF');
    },function(){
        $(this).css('color','rgb(200,200,200)');
    });
    $('body ul li').each(function(){
        var tamcompleto = $(this).height() + 'px';
        $(this).hover(
            function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({height:tamcompleto},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
            },
            function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
            }
        );
        $(this).css('height','50px');
    }); 
    $('.objeto').each( function(){
        $(this).click(function() {
            var center   = 'height=380,width=900,top='+((screen.width - 900)/2)+',left='+((screen.height - 380)/2);
            var address = $(this).attr('id');
            window.open (address,'Verarticulo', center); 
        });
        $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).css('backgroundColor','rgb(255,122,79)');
        },function() {
            $(this).css('backgroundColor','rgb(200,200,200)');
        });
    });
    $('.elastica img').each(function(){
        $(this).css('width','100px');
        $(this).hover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({width: 200}, 150);
        },function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({width: 100}, 150);
        });
    });
    $('.elastica').click(function(){
         $('#imgampliada').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    });
    $('.icon').each(function(){
        var newwidth = $(this).attr('data-width');
        var newposition = $(this).attr('data-position');
        $(this).find('img').hover(function(){
            $('#choice').html($(this).attr('id'));
            $('#choice').stop(false, true).animate({width: newwidth, left: newposition}, 200);
        })
    }); 
    $('#iconwrapper').mouseout(function(){
        $('#choice').html('');
        $('#choice').stop(false, true).animate({width: 0}, 100);
    });
```

});

Main suspect: Do custom data tags work under IE8?

Comment: @serv-bot 22: Does jslint.com work for jQuery-code?

Comment: Thanks, I'd never heard about that tool. I fixed a small syntax error, but its giving off this wierd error now: Error:
Implied global: $ 1,2,3,5,7,10,13,14,15,17,20,23,25,28,32,34,37,40,41,42,44,45,50,51,52,53,54,55,58,59,60, document 1, screen 27, window 29, gridimage 45,46,48

Comment: @serv-bot 22: It recognizes `$` as implicit global variable, because it does not know about jQuery (you need to include it in the test to eliminate that error). Variables that are declared without the `var` keyword are globals. This can be a quite subtile error. This is why jslint reports it.

Comment: How do I add it? I appended it to the beginning of the code, and now it gives off a BUNCH of errors.

Comment: @serv-bot 22: Simply leave jQuery out and do not worry about this error. jQuery does not pass jslint, which is the reason for your bunch of errors.

Comment: Well, then apart from the jquery errors, the code is fine. Any ideas on what I could do to fix this?

Comment: @serv Is `gridimage` a global variable ??

Comment: @serv-bot 22: Regarding your main suspect: No, this does not work in IE8, as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IE to debug, just hit F12 and select 'Script' in the debugger window

Answer (score 0):

mouseover and mouseout could be replaced with hover()

```
$().hover(
    function(){
        //
    },
    function(){
        //
    }
);
```

Comment: `mouseover` and `mouseout` are not equal to `hover`. `hover` uses `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. This makes a significant difference.

Comment: Elusive, can you please explain a bit further?